# Import data from Azure Blob Storage in Excel (Mac)

Tags: excel, azure-blob-storage

I'd like to import data from an XLS residing in an Azure Blob Container. I haven't found a direct option within Excel for doing this.

I checked Powerquery but couldn't find an appropriate import option.

Can anybody share information on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved the issue:

Within Azure Store explorer I

- selected the blob
- right clicked on the Excel File
- copied the shared access signature

Within Excel, in the Data ribbon, I opened the Power query editor and inserted

```
let
  Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("SAS URL goes in here"), null, true),
  #"Navigation 1" = Source{[Item = "Sheet1", Kind = "Sheet"]}[Data],
  #"Promoted Header" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Navigation 1", [PromoteAllScalars = true]),
  #"Transformed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Header", {{"createdAt", type datetime}, {"quantity", Int64.Type}, {"displayName", type text}, {"title", type text}, {"sku", type text}, {"color", type text}, {"sex", type text}, {"season", type text}, {"refunded", Int64.Type}, {"certification", type text}, {"net_price", Int64.Type}, {"pricing", type text}}, "de")
in
  #"Transformed column type"
```

Same works with CSV

```
let
  source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents("SAS URL goes in here"), [Delimiter = ",", Columns = 12, QuoteStyle = QuoteStyle.None]),
  promotedHeader = Table.PromoteHeaders(source, [PromoteAllScalars = true]),
  transformedColumnTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(promotedHeader, {{"createdAt", type datetime}, {"quantity", Int64.Type}, {"displayName", type text}, {"title", type text}, {"sku", type text}, {"color", type text}, {"sex", type text}, {"season", type text}, {"refunded", Int64.Type}, {"certification", type text}, {"net_price", Int64.Type}, {"pricing", type text}}, "de")
in
  transformedColumnTypes
```

Answer (score 0):

- Click on Data -> Get Data -> From Azure -> From Azure Blob Storage
  [image]
- Enter the Blob storage account name or URL
  [image]
- Give account key / SAS if it is private blob storage.

[image]

- Click on the required file
- Click Load.
- Data will be imported into excel worksheet.

Note: I have tried the above using Excel for Microsoft 365(office 365).

Comment: I'm running Excel 16.57 on Mac and don't see 'From Azure'. Are you running it on a Mac?